# Filterrific and Multitenancy, Limiting Active Record Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, filterrific

I am trying to limit the results of the filterrific search to only instances that have a given client_id.

My set up is as follows:

```
# customers_controller.rb
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
    Customer,
    params[:filterrific],
    select_options: {
      sorted_by: Customer.options_for_sorted_by,
      with_agent_id: Agent.options_for_select
    },
  ) or return
```

Is there a way to limit the returned active record results, like Customer.where('client_id', 2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
    Customer,
    params[:filterrific],
    select_options: {
      sorted_by: Customer.options_for_sorted_by,
      with_agent_id: Agent.options_for_select
    },
  ) or return
       @customers = @filterrific.find.where(client_id: 2).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) # add paginate if you require pagination
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Hadn't gotten as far as discovering that `.find` returns the active record. Although in retrospect it makes sense given one calls paginate on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually figured it out.  Looks like you are just passing the FIND into the @filterrific definition...

```
@appointments = @filterrific.find.where(vendor_id: @vendor_locations.select(:vendor_id))
.page(params[:page])
```